# React Native building new APKs but does not overwrites previous ones

Tags: android, react-native, apk, android-build

For a few days I have noticed that when I generate APKs, the previous ones are not overwritten.

Let me explain: I use the `react-native run-android` and `react-native run-android --variant=release` commands to generate the APKs in debug and the APKs in release respectively.

The problem is that the APKs that I had previously generated remain in the FileSystem (`$MY_PROJECT_DIR/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk` and `$MY_PROJECT_DIR/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk`)of my PC. So, the build generation commands are successful, but the APKs are not updated.

In fact, I am forced to manually delete the previous APKs from the above paths and redo the builds, so it works and I have no more problems.

This wasn't the case before and I don't know what I might have changed, it's possible that a gradle update could be the cause? In any case, is there a solution to this? It would be handy not to have to manually delete old APKs before each build.

Comment: You should manually clean the android build using gradlew clean command before making release apk

Comment: Can you please check if there are any permission issues?

Comment: @Mantu yes, may be this is a workaround similar to deleting manually the apks.

Comment: @Lukas from the logs I noticing anything issues about permissions.